# Capture data from a modal popup as part of the partial view with Html.BeginCollectionItem

Tags: asp.net-core

I am unable to properly **capture data from a modal popup** as part of the **Html.BeginCollectionItem** for a **dynamic collection**. Could someone point me to a sample?

MainForm.cshtml loads a partial view for items in the model.

_Item.cshtml

Here you would see that I am trying to get the sub-items via modal popup.

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items"))
    {
       ... details of items

       // To get Sub item details via popup
<input class="btn-primary" type="button" value="Add new SubItem" />

        <div class="modal fade" id="NewPage_@Model.AddPage.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby='Button+@Model.AddPage.Id' aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                loading ...
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    }
```

_SubItem.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("SubItems"))
        {
             ... details of sub-items
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify more about your question?

Comment: @FeiHan I am trying to capture nested dynamic collections using popups.